# Why is the response of REST API not in JSON format in my code, but is in the correct format with Google extension "restman"?

Tags: c#, json, rest, format, response

Why is the response of REST API is not in JSON format in my code? But with Google extension "RestMan" it is in correct format. My code is like this:

```cs
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://personnel.fasau.ac.ir:8085/PersonApi/api/Token/Login", new NameValueCollection()
  {
    {"Username", "name"},
    {"Password", "pass"}
  });
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

The response I get is like this:

```
\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\05��n�P\u0010�_�b�D\\�#�3�`��1\u001c\u000e\aÎ�[.\a�\b\u000e6Q\u0017ݴY�=��*+}\u0018��Lq��f4��#���0$�i�<6�a7f�>ߕ�#�;�I���M�kN�q0՞�\u0012��\\�jy�%s]�\u001fD\\X�c�Oa�6�=,\v�À(\u000e�ׁbՖ[�إ+ª�K�銕*�A\u001b�t�/��+Z�pPe\u0003\t�\u0005h �w\u0006�:TX��I�e��a��JR;\u000e�C%Yc\"/\u0093T�*�\u0002Jr��ҥ2@%��lv2�X�\u0001R1�8䴓��Ǎ�8\u0001�]�ru�hD��\u000fv�`ċ.��f�Gm�� �u=����\u001f�\u0004#N��\f�!�z\u001b\u0017�\u0001�uCa��\\\a�\u0016��B\u0015���it�\u001f��K7\u0019�\r%\u0017�\u0012�\u0006����Ln�\r}��\u0011\a��G��iબ��0����\u0004C\u0001�p��\u0004�\u0016�<Z�.�}v]���\u001e \u0014*������\u0012>��u�x��J��6$�������ML�m��T�7�S�3\u0019��>�\u001a`<��\u00193�R\u0018\u0014�������_���2���o����\\_����\a���=�X\u000e�1\u0003�z_㴡7[��?_���?n����u�/\u007f\u0001b�Q�S\u0002\0\0
```

The response body of "RestMan" is like this (in correct format):

```json
{
    "Valid": true,
    "Token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Im56RDhteWJaUkVkV2Fsdmppa2hCM0Y5RHdnQWMyRm5UczZja3ZMUjNiUkxFaTUwUGNrYUt3VTdoZHpKbS9KM1FlYkR0ZDhkZUlSZjBFMHdHcUJJRE01VVRld1JDS3pZOWU0akxKMzhBSmY3MVBQaU9RdG50YXNzYlV0Q0pRK2dCUlJ1a01oQTBUKzhFWnkvenNkQ0NUbTYzR01GTFR2S2NwOGtLUVh0ZmJ1WT0iLCJEaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6IlciLCJuYmYiOjE2MDk2ODI3NDksImV4cCI6MTYwOTY5MzU0OSwiaWF0IjoxNjA5NjgyNzQ5LCJpc3MiOiJCcHRzb2Z0LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6IkJwdHNvZnQuY29tIn0.4J0h30Gd1RzWl3tBulGWEQwcQW_PnTV0VTDFAb8S-vg",
    "FullName": "کاربر وب سرویس",
    "Photo": null,
    "ErrorTitle": "دانشگاه فسا"
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the headers in the response - I *suspect* you'll find that it's got a content encoding of gzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an [accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept),

```cs
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```

**Update**: It is also possible that the response in compressed using Gzip compression. Use a helper function to decompress the string first and then use a JSON serializer to serialize it.

A helper function I use to decompress Gzip in my code,

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

public string DecompressString(string s, Encoding encoding)
{
  // obtaining bytes from the string in the below step
  // In my case, it was a base 64 string
  // If not use encoding.GetBytes() function
  var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s); 

  using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
      gs.CopyTo(mso);
    }
    return encoding.GetString(mso.ToArray());
  }
}
```

```cs
var originalRes = // call your function here
var decompressedRes = helper.DecompressGzipString(originalRes, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: after setting accept header, still the same problem.

Comment: @mandanahosseini The response could be compressed using Gzip. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you, it was compressed, that solved my problem. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try unicode encoding:

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(response);
```

Comment: with unicode encoding now i get this response:   "謟\b\0\0\u0004鄽狉䂛䔔䕿嫅ㅱ깈㭈\u0c5b䄂虣虮퍝脐䁨蓖꧔눬뱉翈姈咥쟎艧좲嗪瞽\uabeeꘐ쩅睍綛\ua6fc櫌쩮❥伣刴藘䎡\u0ba6킠窷軭䳉ힿ痋暈螮ꒄ잢䀴銟�廅ꑿ蚏\ua955嘦栄暣⠔覱怫諠Ɱ㻨锣ᢈꖭ刄⢅Ꚕ鐂繼\u2429计숗靁狢䕜㸬灸⏭嚉ﲁ䈠줟눖₄ꅰ賃鷘붃剟\u2d2f귳↭噆뚠ꎴ햖鲮\u0dceᇓ趕σ⢏᎓阊⢣䩜䁮쁣葔㔵⣆촀밗ቛ牭쩲ј蹲抳硒솁ꇇ߂湡쥣\ufde0ꠒ㔞�ޗ쥤慼\u0cce蜅䶠甴￬价ﭮ命蕅劽䭄┮ጠ拉ꭰ桗୴횣觶쭠Ɛ\u2dafꁰ\ufaf2㦪햂ᣃ䜰찂晴畞缋䬮飄⬷䡰뺼䪄╿洘ܺ뢇㢑缵扇髙皌幏縻䰾킶妩體詖폒薇ꦉ㣓㷪ὦ↹ԩ쪸뛺翟틮皽솗ꗵᵻ潴䟧훷佳덹롫�䏣�马徍홍ퟎ�ﳛ렾杵쯮⅟礭匥\u0002�"