# Dart convert string without quotes to json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, tostring

I am trying to convert a string to json string.

String I get:

```
String myJSON =  '{codigo: 1050, decricao: Mage x, qntd: 1, tipo: UN, vUnit: 10,9, vTotal: 10,90}';
```

String I need:

```
String myJSON =  '{"codigo": "1050", "decricao": "Mage x", "qntd": "1", "tipo": "UN", "vUnit": "10,9", "vTotal": "10,90"}';
```

Could someone shed some light on how I can add the quotes?

Comment: try jsonEncode(myJsonString);

Comment: if you aren't getting JSON format from API, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65559356/10157127)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily convert a String using `replaceAll`.

Code:

```
  String myJSON =  '{codigo: 1050, decricao: Mage x, qntd: 1, tipo: UN, vUnit: 10,9, vTotal: 10,90}';
  myJSON = myJSON.replaceAll('{', '{"');
  myJSON = myJSON.replaceAll(': ', '": "');
  myJSON = myJSON.replaceAll(', ', '", "');
  myJSON = myJSON.replaceAll('}', '"}');
  print(myJSON);
```

Output:

```
{"codigo": "1050", "decricao": "Mage x", "qntd": "1", "tipo": "UN", "vUnit": "10,9", "vTotal": "10,90"}
```

Comment: Not good if you have '{codigo: 1050, decricao: Mage x "with some quoted text: and some text with commas, and points", qntd: 1, tipo: UN, vUnit: 10,9, vTotal: 10,90}';

Answer (score 2):

Convert using json encode

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
    String myJSON =  '{codigo: 1050, decricao: Mage x, qntd: 1, tipo: UN, vUnit: 10,9, vTotal: 10,90}';
    String str = encoder.convert(myJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted Maciej Szakacz's answer to work for my use case, which is nested json. I'll provide the code below:

```
String jsonAddQuotes(String json){
  json = json.replaceAll('{', '{"');
  json = json.replaceAll(': ', '": "');
  json = json.replaceAll(', ', '", "');
  json = json.replaceAll('}', '"}');
  
  json = json.replaceAll('"{', '{');
  json = json.replaceAll('}"', '}');
  return json;
}
```

As commented on his answer, this won't work if you use `:` `{` `}` or `,` in your json values.