# Dart: How to convert json string without quotes to Map

Tags: json, flutter, dart

how to convert json string without quotes to Map.

I tried below code on `https://dartpad.dev/` but not working:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  final String raw = "{data: {name: joy, tags: aa,bb, city: jakarta}}";
  print('Test 1: $raw');
  
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = json.decode(raw);
  print('Test 2: $result');
}
```

And this is the error for above code:

```dart
Test 1: {data: {name: joy, tags: aa,bb, city: jakarta}}
Uncaught Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1
```

And I know this because my json is invalid. How to convert my json string without quotes to json string with quotes?

Actual result is:

```dart
{data: {name: joy, tags: aa,bb, city: jakarta}}
```

Expected result is:

```dart
{"data": {"name": "joy", "tags": "aa,bb", "city": "jakarta"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it with below code, refer from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025841/21092577

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  
  String raw = "{data: {name: joy, tags: aa,bb, city: jakarta}}";
  print("Test 0: $raw");
  
  String jsonString = _convertToJsonStringQuotes(raw: raw);
  print("Test 1: $jsonString");
  
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = json.decode(jsonString);
  print('Test 2: $result');
  
}


String _convertToJsonStringQuotes({required String raw}) {
    String jsonString = raw;

    /// add quotes to json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('{', '{"');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(': ', '": "');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(', ', '", "');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('}', '"}');

    /// remove quotes on object json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"{"', '{"');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"}"', '"}');

    /// remove quotes on array json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"[{', '[{');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('}]"', '}]');

    return jsonString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate

The json should be

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "joy",
        "tags": "aa,bb",
        "city": "Jakarta"
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=349b90b747339195cf01d738afb65f7e)

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  final String raw = "{" +
"   \"data\": {" +
"       \"name\": \"joy\"," +
"       \"tags\": \"aa,bb\"," +
"       \"city\": \"Jakarta\"" +
"   }" +
"}";


  Map<dynamic, dynamic> resultMap = json.decode(raw);
  print('Test 3: $resultMap');
}
```

Comment: can u give me full example? bcz i need the result as `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

Comment: no it's not map, but as String. Could u try it on `https://dartpad.dev/`? I try ur code not work

Comment: and also pls change `final result` to `final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result`, if not the result as `dynamic`

Comment: Your json is invalid check answer.  I think json should be {
 "data": {
  "name": "joy",
  "tags": "aa,bb",
  "city": "Jakarta"
 }
}

Comment: That's my question right? I need to convert `raw` to correct json format. Because right now it's invalid json (no quotes).